# DBGSESSID, XDEBUG_SESSION_START - Что это?

Tags: php

Доброго времени. В движке нашел исключения для юрлов в виде двух глобальных переменных

```
DBGSESSID и  XDEBUG_SESSION_START
```

Т.е сайт сейчас открывается по index.php?DBGSESSI и index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START

Подскажите, для чего они нужны ? В гугле более менее для меня понятную инфу на русском не нашел .

Спасибо

Comment: для отладки. DBG  - Debug/Debugging...... xdebug это расширение в php как раз с помощью чего происходит отладка..... у отладчика как раз может быть свой идентифиатор и параметр что началась отладка.

Comment: подскажите, ну у меня он вызывается через браузер , но ничего не появляется, никаких сообщений. Значит - это просто остатки кода или просто нужно какие-то параметры добавлять, чтоб что-то произошло ?

Comment: Без понятия. Пока непонятно (потому что вы не сказали), что это за движок. Может чей-то самописный и это нужная штука там. Вообще в урле не должны автоматически появлятся эти GET параметры если вы не находитесь в режиме отладки, это совершенно точно.

Comment: вообще говоря, чтобы "что-то произошло" (в смысле - чтобы вы смогли как-то проводить отладку) - надо установить и настроить серверную часть xdebug, установить и настроить клиент-отладчик, настроить между ними коннект... ну и главное - понять, что именно вы хотите отлаживать-то?

Comment: ну т.е. если вопрос был "что это?" - то вам ответили: "это для отлатчика"... если хотите зачем-то использовать отладчик - сначала поймите "зачем", потом сходите на xdebug.org, сделайте все, что там написано... вот если что-то не получится - возвращайтесь сюда, говорите, что получилось а что нет, это уже будет другое дело :)